# Mapscript_csharp issue with version 7.0.4

Tags: mapserver, mapscript

Processing a map file with use of mapscript_csharp.dll (version 7.0.1) and map contains a few WMS HTTP layers and some are local shapefiles.

After upgrading from Mapserver 7.0.1 to latest version 7.0.4 by copying necessary (e.g.cgi-bin) dll's to my application bin and correct versions of libmap/mapscript dll (concerning oracle)  I get an error when executing the map.draw() function (using the same map as with 7.0.1):

`"drawGDAL(): Unable to access file. GDALDatasetRasterIO() failed: libpng: bad parameters to zlib"
[System.ApplicationException]: {"drawGDAL(): Unable to access file. GDALDatasetRasterIO() failed: libpng: bad parameters to zlib"}
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
HelpLink: null
HResult: -2146232832
InnerException: null
Message: "drawGDAL(): Unable to access file. GDALDatasetRasterIO() failed: libpng: bad parameters to zlib"
Source: "mapscript_csharp"`

If I remove the HTTP WMS layers from my map file it works.

Could someone explain what I am missing and/or what file could not be accessed?

If any other info needed, let me know.